# ACF Custom fields empty display text

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Can someone know the answer about it
I have field set and i want when they are empty show some text now there is showing nothing

```
<div class="place-bottom-row">
    <?php if(get_field('pojedynczy_wpis')): 
    $i = 0; 
    $today = date('d-m-Y'); //This has to match the format of your date field
    ?>
        <?php while(has_sub_field('pojedynczy_wpis')): ?>
            <?php if(strtotime($today) <= strtotime(get_sub_field('danie_na_dzien'))){ ?>
                <?php if($i < 2){ ?>
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                    <?php the_sub_field('danie_rodzaj'); ?>
                    <?php the_sub_field('danie_opis'); ?>
                    <?php the_sub_field('danie_cena'); ?>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else:  ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- place bottom row end -->
```

Comment: You do not have to wrap every individual line with `<?php ?>`. Instead, wrap whole sections of php, together.

Comment: I know but this is not answer for my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `the_sub_field()` (which `echo`es the return value), you should use [get_sub_field()](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/):

```
<?php echo get_sub_field('danie_rodzaj') ? get_sub_field('danie_rodzaj') : 'Custom Text instead'; ?>
```

This will allow you to test if there's a value, before echoing it.

Comment: This solution *does* work. If it doesn't, you should be receiving an error, or at least some kind of content. Are you seeing the custom text?

Comment: No, there is nothing showing not error or not even text just blank space

Comment: It's not possible to show nothing, unless your sub field has no data associated with it. That snippet will **always** output something.